# Connecting a DataSet to Combobox.DataSource, via DataBindings

Tags: c#, database, combobox, datasource

how to connect data from a DataSet to a DataSoure Combobox?
Provided that the Combobox is in an array of type Control

I do this, but the error "System.ArgumentException: for a composite DataBinding data source may be IList or IListSource."

```
conn.Open();
myOleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(combo_querys[tabNames[tabs_combo.SelectedIndex]][0,j], conn);
myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = myOleDbCommand;
myDataSet = new DataSet();
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
myDataAdapter.Update(myDataSet);
tb.DataBindings.Clear();
 
string[] ds = new string[myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
for (int f = 0; f < myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; f++)
{
    ds[f] = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[f][0].ToString();
}
Binding d = new Binding("DataSource", ds,"");
 
Binding gf = new Binding("DisplayMember", combo_querys[tabNames[tabs_combo.SelectedIndex]][1, j], "");
tb.DataBindings.Add(d);
tb.DataBindings.Add(gf);
                        
 conn.Close();
j++;
```

Tell me how to connect

Comment: A combox is a two dimensional object [rows][columns].  A DataSet is three dimension because you have [tables][rows][columns].  You can only bind a combobox to one table. I think you have an array of comboboxes one for each table.  So you need to have a binding for each comboxbox/table.

Comment: tried to connect DataTable.
All the same error.
In my example, I am not passing the DataSet itself
And the string array to which I pass the values ​​from the DataSet.

Maybe the error is due to the fact that I pass the DataMemeber with the value ""?

Comment: I can't tell what is causing issue.  Maybe look at following to see if you binding are correct : https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html